# Is there anyway to modify a variable inside a python try

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to add global after the try and it didn't work
I want to fix the code to work like this :
if Kouki variable contains "webmail", the webmailpage variable = kouki and after that I can use the new value of the webmailpage variable outside the try and except thanks !

```
webmailpage=""
for cookie in e:
  try:

      Kouki=cookie["domain"]
      webmail="webmail"
      if Kouki.find(webmail)!= -1 :
          webmailpage=Kouki

  except:
     continue
print(webmailpage)
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to catch in the `try .. except`? It's most likely that you're just ignoring an error without realising it, because you wrote the `try .. except` to catch everything and just continue.

Comment: What happens when you run your code?  What errors do you get?  Please include some sample input data, expected output and actual output?

Comment: @eqong, I think their problem is that they're not actually getting any errors, because they are catching and ignoring them all with a blanket `except`

Comment: I used the try and except to ignore the errors so the for loop continue looping

Comment: The problem is when i run the code the webmailpage variable is still blank ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description no `try` `except` is needed at all.

Just use a conditional statement.

```
webmailpage = ""
kouki = cookie.get("domain","")
if "webmail" in kouki:
    webmailpage = kouki
print(webmailpage)
```

Unless you expect `cookie` to not contain the `"domain"` key in which case you could do this:

```
webmailpage = ""
try:
    kouki = cookie.get("domain","")
    if "webmail" in kouki:
        webmailpage = kouki
except KeyError:
    pass
print(webmailpage)
```

Comment: but its a for loop, the code may face some errors when executing it so the exception is needed it will continue looping if it face an error

Comment: @MedAli The only error possible is the KeyError that Is caught in my second example. Except for I guess if Kuoki could sometimes be some non sequence data type